# Why is the multiplication happening only after refresh?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a calculator. This has a form which, for certain calculations, works only when I refresh the page. Addition works but multiplication only works after refresh. Why is that?

I don't want to use JQuery!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Card Form</title>

  <link href="styles/cardform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body onload='hideTotal()'>
  <div id="wrap">
    <form action="" id="cardform" onsubmit="return false;">
      <div>
        <div class="cont_order">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Check Quotes</legend>
            <label>Size Of the Card</label>
            <label>Width in cm:  </label> <input type="text" id="width" />
            <label>Height in cm:  </label> <input type="text" id="height" />
            <br/>

            <br/>

            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcard1" value="Round13"  onclick=""/>Standard</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcard1" value="Round14" onclick="" />Toughened</label><br/>

            <br/>
            <label>Card:  </label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcard2" value="Round17"  onclick=""/>Clear</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcard2" value="Round18" onclick="" />Frosted</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcard2" value="Round19" onclick="" />Leaded</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcard2" value="Round20" onclick="" />White Bar</label>
            <br/>
            <label>Frame:  </label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcard3" value="Round21"  onclick=""/>uPVC</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcard3" value="Round22" onclick="" />Metal</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcard3" value="Round23"  onclick=""/>Wood</label>

            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onClick="calculateTotal()" />
            <INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="RESET" onClick="resetIt()" />
            <div id="totalPrice"></div>

          </fieldset>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!--End of wrap-->

</body>
<script>
  var size1 = document.getElementById("width").value;
  var size2 = document.getElementById("height").value;

  var total_size = ((size1 * size2) / 10000);

  var card_prices = new Array();


  card_prices["Round13"] = (total_size * 67);
  card_prices["Round14"] = (total_size * 87);

  card_prices["Round17"] = (total_size * 0.05);
  card_prices["Round18"] = (total_size * 0.65);
  card_prices["Round19"] = (total_size * 0.85);
  card_prices["Round20"] = (total_size * 0.95);






  function getCardSizePrice2() {

    var cardSizePrice = 0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="cardform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cardform"];
    //Get a reference to the card the user Chooses name=selectedCard":
    var selectedCard1 = theForm.elements["selectedcard1"];
    //Here since there are 4 radio buttons selectedCard.length = 4
    //We loop through each radio buttons
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedCard1.length; i++) {
      //if the radio button is checked
      if (selectedCard1[i].checked) {
        //we set cardSizePrice to the value of the selected radio button
        //i.e. if the user choose the 8" card we set it to 25
        //by using the card_prices array
        //We get the selected Items value
        //For example card_prices["Round8".value]"
        cardSizePrice = card_prices[selectedCard1[i].value];
        //If we get a match then we break out of this loop
        //No reason to continue if we get a match
        break;
      }
    }
    //We return the cardSizePrice
    return cardSizePrice;
  }

  function getCardSizePrice3() {

    var cardSizePrice = 0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="cardform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cardform"];
    //Get a reference to the card the user Chooses name=selectedCard":
    var selectedCard = theForm.elements["selectedcard2"];
    //Here since there are 4 radio buttons selectedCard.length = 4
    //We loop through each radio buttons
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedCard.length; i++) {
      //if the radio button is checked
      if (selectedCard[i].checked) {

        cardSizePrice = card_prices[selectedCard[i].value];

        break;
      }
    }

    return cardSizePrice;
  }

  function getCardSizePrice4() {
    card_prices["Round21"] = 2;
    card_prices["Round22"] = 5;
    card_prices["Round23"] = 5;

    var cardSizePrice = 0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="cardform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cardform"];
    //Get a reference to the card the user Chooses name=selectedCard":
    var selectedCard = theForm.elements["selectedcard3"];
    //Here since there are 4 radio buttons selectedCard.length = 4
    //We loop through each radio buttons
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedCard.length; i++) {
      //if the radio button is checked
      if (selectedCard[i].checked) {

        cardSizePrice = card_prices[selectedCard[i].value];

        break;
      }
    }

    return cardSizePrice;
  }
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');

  function calculateTotal() {
    //Here we get the total price by calling our function
    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
    var cardPrice = getCardSizePrice2() + getCardSizePrice3() + getCardSizePrice4();
    //display the result

    divobj.style.display = 'block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Card: &pound;" + " " + cardPrice;
    displaytotal(divobj);

  }

  function displaytotal() {


  }

  function hideTotal() {
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display = 'none';
  }

  function resetIt() {
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display = 'none';
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You're running JS outside of a dom-ready event, so (a) you may be running it before the elements are event rendered, and (b) on render the inputs will be empty, so there's nothing to multiply by. I can't really follow your code--it's better to create (and post) a minimal example and focus on that first, then expand to your complete usecase.

Comment: I don't know much about javascript logic so I don't really know how to make it Dom ready

Comment: Just got it working. It was just an stupid mistake. Thanks Dave

Comment: You can't dump 179 lines of code in our laps and expect us to know what it's supposed to do. At the very least, give us an example of which inputs are supposed to produce which outputs.

Comment: -_- well I just dont know how to delete this question. I really want to!

Comment: @Falak Don't delete the question, but please edit it and explain what problem you found that corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you've found your issue (I believe it had to do with the fact that you had your code set up with a submit button and you had totals being calculated as soon as the page load event triggered, rather than upon a click of the total button).

But, beyond that, you may still want to look at this answer very carefully as the code you have is just awful in many regards:

**HTML**:

- Your HTML was not being used correctly. You were not using `<label>`
  or `<fieldset>` elements properly.
- Since you were really just needing a calculator that doesn't actually
  submit the data anywhere, you shouldn't have a submit button.
- You were using inline HTML event handlers (`onsubmit`, `onclick`,
  etc.), which should not be used because:

  - They create "spaghetti code" that is difficult to read and leads to
    duplication of code.
  - They cause global event handling wrapper functions to be implicitly
    created around the attribute values that you supply that make the
    binding of the `this` object not work as expected.
  - They don't follow **[W3C Standards for Event Handling](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20131105/#methods-1)**

**JavaScript:**

- You were setting up variables for the HTML elements you were going to
  use inside your various functions, which meant that every time the
  function runs, it has to re-scan the document all over again to find
  the element.
- You were using an array when an Object was more appropriate.
- You had essentially the same function written 3 times instead of just
  having it once and passing an argument to it that can change as you
  need it to.

Here is a cleaned up version that follows best-practices, semantics and doesn't repeat itself. See the inline comments for specifics.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  // Get references to DOM elements that we'll need access to just once. Don't set variables
  // up to store their values at first. Set the variable to the elmement. That way, you can
  // go back to the element as often as you need to in order to get any property value you
  // like, without having to re-scan the document for it all over again:
  var size1 = document.getElementById("width");
  var size2 = document.getElementById("height");
  var divObj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  var theForm = document.getElementById("cardform");
  var selectedCard1 = theForm.querySelectorAll("[name=selectedcard1]");
  var selectedCard2 = theForm.querySelectorAll("[name=selectedcard2]");
  var selectedCard3 = theForm.querySelectorAll("[name=selectedcard3]"); 
  var calc = document.querySelector("input[type=button]");
  var res = document.querySelector("input[type=reset]");
  
  // Set up event handlers for various DOM elements:
  calc.addEventListener("click", calculateTotal);
  res.addEventListener("click", reset);  
  
  // Create a storage mechanism that holds "keys" and associated "values"
  // Arrays can only do this with sequential numeric indexes. Objects, do it
  // with string property names.
  var card_prices = {};
  
  // No reason to have 3 functions that all do basically the same thing but only 
  // to different objects. Just have one function that accepts a reference to the
  // radiobuttons it needs to work with
  function getCardSizePrice(cards){  

    var cardSizePrice = 0;
    
    // Loop through each radio button in the passed in group
    for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(cards[i].checked) {
            // Lookup the value of the selected radio button in our object and get the 
            // associate property value
            cardSizePrice = card_prices[cards[i].value];
            
            // No reason to continue if we get a match
            break;
        }
    }
    // We return the cardSizePrice
    return cardSizePrice;
  }     
  
  function calculateTotal() {
  
    // You didn't have the following code in this funciton, so it was running immediately
    // when the page loaded.
  
    // Remember, values that you take out of form elements are strings!
    // If you want to treat them as numbers, you should explicitly convert them
    // to numbers first:
    var s1 = parseFloat(size1.value);
    var s2 = parseFloat(size2.value);
  
    var total_size = (s1 * s2) / 10000;

    // Set all the property values
    card_prices["Round13"] = total_size * 67,
    card_prices["Round14"] = total_size * 87,
    card_prices["Round17"] = total_size * .05,
    card_prices["Round18"] = total_size * .65,
    card_prices["Round19"] = total_size * .85,
    card_prices["Round20"] = total_size * .95, 
    card_prices["Round21"] = 2;
    card_prices["Round22"] = 5;
    card_prices["Round23"] = 5;    
 
    // Here we get the total price by calling our function
    // Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
    var cardPrice =  getCardSizePrice(selectedCard1) + 
                     getCardSizePrice(selectedCard2) + 
                     getCardSizePrice(selectedCard3);
   
    displayTotal(cardPrice);
  }
  
  function displayTotal(price) {
    // display the result
    divObj.classList.remove("hidden");
    divObj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Card: &pound;"  + " " +  price.toFixed(2);
  }
  
  function reset(){
    divObj.innerHTML = "";
  }

});
```

```css
#totalPrice { background-color:#ff0; } // Default style for element
#panel { margin-top: 1em;}
fieldset { margin-bottom:1em; }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <form action="#" id="cardform">
      <div class="cont_order">
         <h1>Check Quotes</h1>
         
         <!-- Fieldsets are for logical grouping of form elements. While they do have a 
              visual component to them, they are primarially for accessibility for
              visually impaired. -->
         <fieldset>
            <legend>Size Of the Card</legend>
            <!-- Labels associate with form elements via the "for" attribute and the target
                 element's "id" attribute. They aren't just for displaying random text.
                 They are a key aspect of designing for accessibility. You can click/touch the 
                 label and activate the associated form element. -->
            <label for="width">Width in cm:</label> <input type="text" id="width">
            <label for="height">Height in cm:</label> <input type="text" id="height">
            <br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="selectedcard1" id="selectedcard1a" value="Round13">
            <label for="selectedcard1a" class='radiolabel'>Standard</label>
            <input type="radio" name="selectedcard1" id="selectedcard1b" value="Round14">
            <label for="selectedcard1b" class='radiolabel'>Toughened</label><br>
          </fieldset>
         <fieldset>
            <legend>Card</legend>          
            <input type="radio" name="selectedcard2" id="selectedcard2a" value="Round17">
            <label for="selectedcard2a" class='radiolabel'>Clear</label>
            <input type="radio" name="selectedcard2" id="selectedcard2b" value="Round18">
            <label for="selectedcard2b" class='radiolabel'>Frosted</label>
            <input type="radio"  name="selectedcard2" id="selectedcard2c" value="Round19">
            <label for="selectedcard2c" class='radiolabel'>Leaded</label>
            <input type="radio"  name="selectedcard2" id="selectedcard2d" value="Round20">
            <label for="selectedcard2d" class='radiolabel'>White Bar</label>
          </fieldset>
         <fieldset>
            <legend>Frame</legend>          
            <input type="radio"  name="selectedcard3" id="selectedcard3a" value="Round21">
            <label for="selectedcard3a" class='radiolabel'>uPVC</label>
            <input type="radio"  name="selectedcard3" id="selectedcard3b" value="Round22">
            <label for="selectedcard3b" class='radiolabel'>Metal</label>
            <input type="radio"  name="selectedcard3" id="selectedcard3c" value="Round23">
            <label for="selectedcard3c" class='radiolabel'>Wood</label>
          </fieldset>
          <div id="panel">
            <input type="button" value="Calculate">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
            <div id="totalPrice"></div>
          </div>
        </div>  
       </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. You did a great job there!

Comment: Hey Scott just one more thing, when I add 'required' property to all fields, it doesnt work on any of he fields! Why is that?

Comment: @Falak `required` doesn't work in most versions of IE. It should work in most others.